# Can we re-enter the US after leaving on the Visa Waiver Programme

Tags: esta, us-visa-waiver-program

Next year we plan on flying to Florida, spend a few days there and then fly to South America and spend five nights there, then fly back to Florida and spend a week there and fly back home (We are British citizens). We were planning on using an ESTA to enter but we have a question:

Will we need to apply for two ESTA, for both entries to the US or can we use the same one and leave and comeback?

Answer (score 1):

[ESTA - Length of Approval](https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/1126/~/esta---length-of-approval)

> Your ESTA authorization is generally valid for **multiple trips over a period of two years** (starting the date that you are approved) or until your passport expires, whichever comes first. As long as you received an ESTA authorization to travel, you do not have to reapply during the validity period. If your ESTA expires while in the US it will not affect your departure.

For clarity, this does not affect your 90 Day limit under the Visa Waiver Program.